# Angular-cli Lifecycle Hooks Not Being Called on Navigation

Tags: angular-cli, google-signin, lifecycle, angular-routing, google-api-js-client

I'm currently working with an angular-cli project. When I load a component after navigating via `router.navigate` the component constructor runs, however, the ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit hooks do not activate.

The route I am on is `/login` and I am navigating to `/controlpanel`

I've read https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8012, but unfortunately that did not help, as polyfills are not affecting my application currently.

The relevant pieces of code are below:

The router.navigate call:

```
public attachSignin(element) {
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {}, (googleUser) => {
        this.googleAuth.auth2 = this.auth2;
        this.googleAuth.userProfile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        this.router.navigate(['/controlpanel']);
    });
  }
```

My routing setup (from a lower module):

```
const dataRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'controlpanel', component: DataHomeComponent },
]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DataHomeComponent,
    GravityMapComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    GlobalModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(dataRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DataModule { }
```

The main application routing file:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule {}
```

One thing to note about the module setup is that there are routes declared in submodules. These submodules are then imported into the main module. The main routing file just declares the RouterModule.forRoot() to be for root - I did my best to follow the architecture presented at: https://angular.io/guide/http

The component to be called:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import gapi from 'gapi'

@Component({
  selector: 'data-home-component',
  templateUrl: './data-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-home.component.css'],
})
export class DataHomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public ngOnInit() {
    console.log("oninit")
  }

  public signOut() {
    gapi.auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
}
```

UPDATE: when I use HashLocationStrategy the component lifecycle hooks run - does anyone know what causes this?

UPDATE: when I remove the injected service, the ngOnInit hook runs when using PathLocationStrategy. Why would the component be returned as an injectable if it is just receiving a singleton service?

UPDATE: I isolated the DataHomeComponent to its most basic form - and it seems that `declare const gapi: any;` for using google's api is what prevents the ngOnInit from running. Any advice on where to declare that variable?

Comment: Read: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks. You have to implement the lifecycle hooks properly in order for them to work. Just adding them to the component without the right `implements` won't work.

Comment: @R.Richards I have the `implements` tags in all the correct places in my code - any further ideas? I will post updated code above

Comment: I am not able to repro this behavior. When I navigate using the router the lifecycle hooks fire.

Comment: interesting, are you navigating after attaching the sign in to the DOM node?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try doing the following?

```
  import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

  constructor (
    ...
    private zone: NgZone
  ){}

  this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {}, (googleUser) => {
      this.googleAuth.auth2 = this.auth2;
      this.googleAuth.userProfile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      this.zone.run(() => { 
          this.router.navigate(['/controlpanel']);
      });
  });
```

I had a very similar issue within the gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn() promise handler that was calling through to my service. Upon route completion none of my ngOnInit methods would be called in components. Sending it through the zone allows reentry to the Angular world as documented here https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run.

Hopefully it helps.